# style.css file in child theme doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

I have created a child theme for my Wordpress theme. I have created a style.css and functions.php file, but it doesn't work on my website and I guess this is my functions.php file problem...

```
* Enqueue styles.
 */
function kava_child_styles_depends( $deps ) {

    $parent_handle = 'kava-parent-theme-style';

    wp_register_style(
        $parent_handle,
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array(),
        kava_theme()->version()
    );

    $deps[] = $parent_handle;

    return $deps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress `handle' is unique, if your parent theme uses the same handle, then the CSS won't load. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

try something like this

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be loading parent theme style and then loading child theme style with the dependency of parent theme. Check following example.

```
function kava_parent_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'kava-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'world-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'kava-style' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kava_parent_theme_enqueue_styles', 11 );
```